# Converting from flat earth to WGS84 with python

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, proj

I'm looking to move from basic 2d Cartesian coordinate system into WGS84.

I know my starting coordinates, however all intermediate points are x/y/z points. of an origin 0,0,0 .

Mathlab has a function of Flat Earth to LLA, would python libraries like proj.4 or any other libraries have built in functions such as Flat Earth to LLA ?

Comment: How big an area? What's the data's accuracy?